# How to remove blank rows in a calculated Power BI table?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a days to report measure where I perform some calculation on each row for the numerator and then filter out blank rows for the denominator. Example table, code and result as follows:

```
Team |  Meeting    |  Report
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |  9/1/2018
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |  7/1/2018
bbb  | 1/1/2018    |  1/2/2018
bbb  | 1/1/2018    | 
ccc  | 1/1/2018    |  3/3/2018
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |
```

This is my function for the average days

```
CALCULATE(
        AVERAGEX(Planning,Planning[Report]-Planning[Meeting]),
        FILTER(Planning,NOT(ISBLANK(Planning[Report])))
    )
```

And I'd like:

```
Team | average
aaa  | 7 (14/2)
bbb  | 31 (31/1)
ccc  | 61 (61/1)
```

Function seems to work but I'm slightly paranoid about my (lack of) understanding of CALCULATE and FILTER than I may be doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function looks fine. The `FILTER` removes any rows with a blank `Report` value and then the `AVERAGEX` evaluates for just those rows.

FYI, for this construction, you don't necessarily need `FILTER` you can just write the following since `CALCULATE` supports basic filtering:

```
Average = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(Planning, Planning[Report] - Planning[Meeting]),
                    NOT(ISBLANK(Planning[Report])))
```

Another way to do this is to use `FILTER` inside of `AVERAGEX` instead of using `CALCULATE`:

```
Average = AVERAGEX(FILTER(Planning, NOT(ISBLANK(Planning[Report]))),
                   Planning[Report] - Planning[Meeting])
```

Comment: Much appreciated - those other examples certainly aid my understanding. Particularly that the second argument of calculate can accept basic filtering without the explicit function.